# Jssor thumbnail navigator with arrows

Tags: jquery, xml, thumbnails, jssor

I use `Jssor` thumbnail navigator with arrows. How to this slider dynamically, image data from xml? This is my code:

xml:

```
<resultset> 
 <error>0</error>
 <product>
  <category>Category</category>
  <name>namenamename</name>  
  <desc>Description</desc>
  <pics>
   <id>product_2_000001</id>
   <id>product_2_000002</id>
   <id>product_2_000003</id>
   <id>product_2_000004</id>
   <id>product_2_000005</id>
   <id>product_2_000006</id>
  </pics>
</product>
```

and my html code:

And my JS

```
function ProductDetail() {
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "products.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var x = $(xml).find("product");
      $(xml).find("product").each(function () {
          $("#product_title").html($(this).find("name").text());
          $("#product_desc").html($(this).find("desc").text());
          $(x).find("pics").each(function(){
                count = $(this).children("id").size();
                alert(count);
                var a = 0;             
                var b = 0;
                while (a < count) {
                    var k = $(this).children("id").text().substr(b, 16);
                    var n = k.slice(7);
                    s = n.slice(1, 2);
                    m = k.slice(10);
                    $("#product").append('<div id="product_gallery' + parseInt(m) + '" style="width: 360px; height: 240px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"  debug-id="slide-' + parseInt(m) +'">' );
                    alert('<img u="image" id="image' + parseInt(m) +'"/>');
                    var i = "#product_gallery" + parseInt(m);
                    $(i).append('<img u="image" id="image' + parseInt(m) +'" border="0" style="width: 360px; height: 240px; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: inline; position: absolute;"  jssor-content="true"/>');
                    $(i).append('<img u="thumb" id="thumb' + parseInt(m) +'" style="display: none;" jssor-content="true"/>');
                    $("#image" + parseInt(m)).attr( "src", function() { return "proc/getitem.php?code="  + domain +  "&id=" + k; });
                    $("#thumb" + parseInt(m)).attr( "src", function() { return "proc/getitem.php?code="  + domain +  "&id=" + k + "&thumb=" + m ;});
                    $("#product").append('</div>');

                b +=16;
                a++;
                }
            });
     });
    }
  });
```

}

Problem: `thumbnail not working, and slider image is not sliding`,

![While loop is working][2]
![Thumb and image source is working][3]

How to fix it, or `jssor` slider dynamically other way?

Comment: images are broken.  Also, the question is too large as you have not narrowed it down or shown errors from what is not working, and why those errors confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

It should wait for the ajax call completion to initialize jssor slider,

```
function ProductDetail() {
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "products.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var x = $(xml).find("product");
      $(xml).find("product").each(function () {
          $("#product_title").html($(this).find("name").text());
          $("#product_desc").html($(this).find("desc").text());
          $(x).find("pics").each(function(){
                count = $(this).children("id").size();
                alert(count);
                var a = 0;             
                var b = 0;
                while (a < count) {
                    var k = $(this).children("id").text().substr(b, 16);
                    var n = k.slice(7);
                    s = n.slice(1, 2);
                    m = k.slice(10);
                    $("#product").append('<div id="product_gallery' + parseInt(m) + '" style="width: 360px; height: 240px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"  debug-id="slide-' + parseInt(m) +'">' );
                    alert('<img u="image" id="image' + parseInt(m) +'"/>');
                    var i = "#product_gallery" + parseInt(m);
                    $(i).append('<img u="image" id="image' + parseInt(m) +'" border="0" style="width: 360px; height: 240px; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: inline; position: absolute;"  jssor-content="true"/>');
                    $(i).append('<img u="thumb" id="thumb' + parseInt(m) +'" style="display: none;" jssor-content="true"/>');
                    $("#image" + parseInt(m)).attr( "src", function() { return "proc/getitem.php?code="  + domain +  "&id=" + k; });
                    $("#thumb" + parseInt(m)).attr( "src", function() { return "proc/getitem.php?code="  + domain +  "&id=" + k + "&thumb=" + m ;});
                    $("#product").append('</div>');

                b +=16;
                a++;
                }
            });
        ...
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
     });
    }
  });
```